# Julia spherical harmonics different from python

Tags: python, julia

I would like to calculate the Spherical Harmonics with Julia. I have done this with the following code:

```
using GSL

function radius(x, y, z)
    return sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
end

function theta(x, y, z)
    return acos(z / radius(x, y, z))
end

function phi(x, y, z)
    return atan(y, x)
end

function harmonics(l, m, x, y, z)
   return (-1)^(m) * GSL.sf_legendre_sphPlm(l, m, cos(theta(x,y,z)))*ℯ^(im*m*phi(x,y,z)) 
end

harmonics(1, 1, 11.66, -35, -35)
harmonics(1, 1, -35, -35, -35)
```

The output is the following:

```
0.07921888327321648 - 0.23779253126608726im
-0.1994711402007164 - 0.19947114020071643im
```

But doing the same with the following python code:

```
import scipy.special as spe
import numpy as np

def radius(x, y, z):
    return np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

def theta(x, y, z):
    return np.arccos(z / radius(x, y, z))

def phi(x, y, z):
    return np.arctan(y / x)

def harmonics(l, m, x, y, z):
    return spe.sph_harm(m, l, phi(x, y, z), theta(x, y, z))

harmonics(1, 1, 11.66, -35, -35)
harmonics(1, 1, -35, -35, -35)
```

Results in the following output:

```
(-0.07921888327321645+0.23779253126608718j)
(-0.19947114020071638-0.19947114020071635j)
```

So the sign of the first result is different. But since only one of the results has a different sign, the cause cannot be in the prefactor `(-1)^m`. I can't see through this anymore and can't explain why the results are different.

Comment: Some special functions have multiple different conventions. Have you checked the docs to make sure they are using the same conventions?

Comment: @OscarSmith I checked this doc for GSL https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html and this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.sph_harm.html for scipy. The definition seems to match.

Comment: The other potential issue is whether `cos` and `exp` are taking the branch cuts that you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by @Oscar Smith got me started on the solution. Julia uses a different convention for the angles returned by `atan`, provided two arguments are passed [[Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.atan-Tuple%7BNumber%7D), [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html)]. If we use `atan(y / x)` instead of `atan(y, x)` in Julia we get the same result.

Comment: For Julia you can link directly to the function's doc: [Link](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.atan-Tuple{Number}). As the docs say, the 2 argument form corresponds to `atan2` or `np.arctan2` (so, `atan(-35, -35)` in Julia and `np.arctan2(-35, -35)` are equal).

Comment: For correctness you should switch both to a two-argument function.  The one-argument form will give incorrect results for odd m over half the range.